# RESAMPLING MULTIPLE .TIFF IMAGES BASED ON ANOTHER ONE TIFF IMAGE

Tags: r, resampling

I have a folder named AOT with image name ranging from 1:744. I have another folder named FOG with one image name- '01DEC2016_0000_L2C_FOG_FOG.tif'. I need to resample 1.tif in AOT with '01DEC2016_0000_L2C_FOG_FOG.tif' in FOG and similarly to all 744 files in AOT folder. I am doing the resampling with the help of loop but one error is coming.

I tried:

```
> require(raster)
#reading files from folder AOT
> flname1 <- list.files(path = 'D:/mtech project/data/DEC 
16/POLLUTANTS/OUTPUT_AOT/', pattern = '.tif')
> nfile1<- length(flname1)
#reading files from folder FOG
> flname2<- raster("D:/mtech project/data/DEC 
 16/FOG/EXTRACTED_IGP/01DEC2016_0000_L2C_FOG_FOG.tif")
#Resampling the data in AOT folder with the data in FOG folder. 
> for (i in 1:nfile1) {
        + r1<-raster(flname1[[i]])
        + r2<-raster(flname2[[i]])
        + rs<-resample(r1,r2,method='ngb')
        + }
  Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  
: 
 Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

Comment: In `list.files` add the parameter `full.names = TRUE`. If your files are not in the working directory you need the full name of the file, including the path.

Comment: Thank you @ricoderks but after doing as suggested by you, i am getting an error-                                                                                                                 
    [for (i in 1:nfile1) {
    + r1<-raster(flname1[[i]])
    +  r2<-raster(flname2[[i]])
    + rs<-resample(r1,r2,method='ngb')
    + writeRaster(rs, paste0('D:/mtech project/data/DEC 
      16/POLLUTANTS/RESAMPLED_SO2/rs_',i,'.img'), overwrite=T)
      + }Error in .local(x, ...) : not a valid subset]

Comment: I don't have any tif files to play with, but are you sure this is correct `r2<-raster(flname2[[i]])`? It seems to me that this is only one file instead of multiple files like `flname1`. Maybe something like `r2<-raster(flname2)`, This can then also be outside the loop.

Comment: @ricoderks if i am doing as directed by you i am having the same problem. is there any other way to write this code. It will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reading a list of files or one file, but immediately creating a raster object.
If you want to resample multiple files against one this could be a solution:

```
library(raster)

# reading files from folder AOT
flname1 <- list.files(path = "D:/mtech project/data/DEC 16/POLLUTANTS/OUTPUT_AOT/"), 
                      pattern = ".tif",
                      full.names = TRUE)

nfile1 <- length(flname1)

# reading file from folder FOG
flname2 <- "D:/mtech project/data/DEC 16/FOG/EXTRACTED_IGP/01DEC2016_0000_L2C_FOG_FOG.tif"

# create raster
r2 <- raster(flname2)

# Resampling the data in AOT folder with the data in FOG folder. 
for (i in 1:nfile1) {
  r1 <- raster(flname1[i])
  rs <- resample(r1, r2, method = "ngb")
}
```

If you want to resample multiple files against multiple files the code will be, but you have to make sure that `flname1` and `flname2` contain the same amount of files:

```
library(raster)

# reading files from folder AOT
flname1 <- list.files(path = "D:/mtech project/data/DEC 16/POLLUTANTS/OUTPUT_AOT/"), 
                      pattern = ".tif",
                      full.names = TRUE) 

nfile1 <- length(flname1)

# reading file from folder FOG
flname2 <- list.files(path = "D:/mtech project/data/DEC 16/FOG/EXTRACTED_IGP/"), 
                      pattern = ".tif",
                      full.names = TRUE)


# R esampling the data in AOT folder with the data in FOG folder. 
for (i in 1:nfile1) {
  r1 <- raster(flname1[i])
  r2 <- raster(flname2[i])
  rs <- resample(r1, r2, method = "ngb")
}
```

Comment: Hereby i am forwarding you the link of my drive in which i have uploaded some data. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Qu53eubPFQHYywJer6vlYI40HtobfpZp Please see to it. in this i have to resample the pollutant data with the RH data.

Comment: Do you want to resample the pollutant data (all 4 files) with 1 file from RH data? I'am just wondering, because your original code shows for `r2` only 1 file.

Comment: yes, because all are of the same spatial resolution.

Comment: Thank you so much it was such a small mistake i was doing. Thank you again!